# Prove that $\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$ converges using power series

Tags: calculus, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, power-series

$$\sin x = x-\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{x^5}{5!}-\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

$$\frac{\sin x}{x} = 1-\frac{x^2}{3!}+\frac{x^4}{5!}-\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Using the d'Alembert test and $t=x^2$ the radius of convergence is $\infty$ so for every x this sum equals the function.

So I have $$\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}$$

But how do I prove that the integral itself converges?

I've had this idea but i'm not sure if it's formally valid:

$$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=
\\
\displaystyle\lim_{M\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_0^M\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=
\\
\displaystyle\lim_{M\to\infty}\displaystyle\int_0^M\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{t^{n}}{(2n+1)!}=
\\
\text{This is a power series so we can integrate each member separably }
\\
\displaystyle\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\displaystyle\int_0^M(-1)^n\frac{t^{n}}{(2n+1)!}=
\\
\displaystyle\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\displaystyle\int_0^M(-1)^n\frac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}=
\\
(\text{Using Newton-Leibniz formula})
\\
\displaystyle\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\frac{M^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)}-\sum0
$$
And because power series-es have uniform convergence the radius has unchanged so if this sum converges therefore the original $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}dx$ converges.

Comment: 1) Don't think you can use uniform convergence of Taylor series if you're calculating an integral over an infinite domain, 2) how do you have the terms tending to $0$ as $M\to\infty$? Wouldn't you expect them to each go to infinity?

Comment: That's why I use the definition of improper integrals. I know that I can switch between finite integrals and infinite sums when there's uniform convergence and the integral between $0$ to $M$ is finite.

Comment: @PanthersFan92, you should realise that (allow me to write $g(n)$ instead of the whole coefficient) from $$\lim_{M\to\infty} \sum_{n=0}^\infty g(n) M^{2n+1}$$ you have no way to prove that that limit is finite. $$\text{That power series ha infinite radius of convergence}=\text{TRUE}$$ $$\text{so the aforementioned limit exists finite}=\text{DOES IT?}$$ In fact, *even if* you interchanged limit and summation, you'd get $$g(0)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\lvert g(n)\rvert\cdot \infty^{2n+1}$$ which looks a lot like an indeterminate form, to me.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 Also $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ has infinite radius of convergence, but $\lim_{M\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{M^n}{n!}=\infty$. Note also that $\int_{0}^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx$ is only conditionally convergent.

Comment: So how do I prove this?

Answer (score 2):

Also $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}$ has infinite radius of convergence, but of course
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^n}{n!}=\infty
$$
It's true that your series has alternating signs, so the example is not of the same kind, but it's too week an argument.

Note also that the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx
$$
is only “conditionally convergent”, in the sense that
$$
\int_0^\infty\left|\frac{\sin x}{x}\right|\,dx
$$
does *not* converge.

---

The usual proof is by considering the integral as
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx+
\int_1^\infty\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx
$$
where the first term poses no problem because the function has a removable singularity at $0$.

The second term is computed by parts:
$$
\int_1^t\frac{\sin x}{x}\,dx=
\Bigl[\frac{-\cos x}{x}\Bigr]_1^t-\int_1^t\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\,dt
$$
Again, the first term poses no issue and
$$
\left|\frac{\cos t}{t^2}\right|\le\frac{1}{t^2}
$$
so the integral is absolutely convergent. Here you may possibly use power series, but I don't think it's worth the trouble.

Comment: I know it's not worth the trouble, but that's what was asked in the question.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 I read the question as “is my method with power series a proof?”

Comment: My question is whether the proof is valid. The reason I prove using power series is because that's what I was asked.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 Well, the proof is not valid.

Comment: Because the idea is completely wrong or because it's not complete? I now see that I neglected the last part where this sum passes the Leibniz test therefore it converges.

Comment: @PanthersFan92 You don't need the Leibniz test: that series has infinite radius of convergence; what you miss is proving that the sums are bounded (a necessary condition for the limit to exist and be finite) and that the limit actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could try Ramanujan's master theorem,

> $$\int_0^\infty y^{s-1}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-y)^k}{k!}\phi(k)dy=\Gamma(s)\phi(-s).$$

With $y=x^2$, our integral is$$\frac12\int_0^\infty y^{-1/2}\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{(-y)^k}{(2k+1)!}dy=\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\phi\left(-\frac12\right)$$with the analytic continuation$$\phi(k)=\frac{k!}{(2k+1)!}=\frac{\Gamma(k+1)}{\Gamma(2k+2)}$$so our result is$$\frac{\Gamma^2\left(\frac12\right)}{2\Gamma\left(1\right)}=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$